# Find a recurrence relation.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ denote the number of n-character sequences of As, Bs, and Cs, in which there is never a C anywhere to the right of an A.

Find a recurrence relation.

EDIT:

we have 2 options A first or not A first

Case 1 Sequence starts with not an A.
so we have 2 options for the first letter ie $2(a_{n-1})$

Case 2 sequence starts with an A.

then we have A$(2^{n-1})$ choice for the remaining terms.

so we have $ a_n = 2(a_{n-1}) + 2^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: "*In which there is never a $C$ anywhere to the right of an $A$*"  By this do you mean that there is no $C$ **immediately following** an $A$?  Or by this do you mean that if there is an $A$ anywhere in the sequence, there is no $C$ anywhere in the sequence to the right of it regardless of distance.  I.e. is the sequence $AABC$ allowed or not?

Comment: Shit ballz your right the sequence AABC is not allowed i think that make it easier

Comment: Both are valid questions, and both are common interpretations of the phrasing of the original question, but the method of solution is different for each.  For the "no $C$'s anywhere to the right of any $A$'s regardless of distance" question, a direct approach is easier: pick the location of the *first* occurrence of an $A$.  Then among the terms before the first $A$, pick whether each is a $B$ or a $C$.  Then among the terms after the first $A$, pick whether each is an $A$ or a $B$.

Comment: its not going to make a difference where the first A shows up because we have 2 choice before it 2 choice after it and one choice where it lands. how do you fix the case where the sequence terminates with no A?

Comment: oh could you just do 2 cases: case 1 you have an A which is $2^{n-1} $ and case two you have no A $2^{n}$ then sum them?

Comment: Quite, for *that* specific interpretation of the problem, except you are missing the term accounting for the *location* of the first $A$, making it instead $n2^{n-1}+2^n$.  I think you'll find that your recurrence relation is correct and generates this as its closed form as well, but I haven't gone through the effort to check that explicitly

Comment: Ah i see you have n choices for the position of the first A. Thank you, you've been very insightful.